# firefox ignoring cached js and css

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, caching

I have .htaccess set up to expire js and css files after 7 days.  ETag is turned off, and gzip / Deflate is turned on.

In my source HTML there are 25 different calls to load JS files.  Not my design.  Here is an example of one of those calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="content/vendors/jquery/rater/jquery.rater-custom.js"></script>
```

The response header from inspection via Firebug:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:             Sun, 20 Jan 2013 23:35:42 GMT
Server:           Apache
Last-Modified:    Sun, 20 Jan 2013 22:49:10 GMT
Accept-Ranges:    bytes
Cache-Control:    max-age=604800
Expires:          Sun, 27 Jan 2013 23:35:42 GMT
Vary:             Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length:   648
Keep-Alive:       timeout=1, max=95
Connection:       Keep-Alive
Content-Type:     application/x-javascript
```

There are also a ton of CSS references.  The page is extremely slow and I am trying to get caching to work, to speed it up.  On IE 9 and Chrome after the first load, this page will render almost instantly...I can tell all these files are being pulled from the cache in those browsers.

On FireFox I cannot get the browser to use the cached copies.  Any idea what I am missing or what could be going on that is forcing FireFox to request fresh copies of these files every single time the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your Firefox configuration? Sometimes people deactivate caching for development reasons, for example via the Developers Toolbar...

Comment: Fernando, you nailed it.  After I had posted this I said to myself something might be "wrong" with FF.  I didn't even know about typing "about:cache" in the FF url bar, but it told me cache was disabled.  Thanks for your reply, you were right!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how Firefox handles automatic caching of files it is served but if your goal is to improve performance by caching files then maybe implementing **ApplicationCache** might be a viable solution.

#### Application Cache

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/offline-browsing-in-html5-with-applicationcache/
- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#applicationcache

Comment: Thanks Mark, good stuff there.  I will review it.  As I said above somehow my cache in FF got turned off...sigh.